# Static Nested class can be extended by not non-static

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

My code is as following :-

A class `T` can extend `ClassO.Four`. `Four` is a static class inside `ClassO` but cannot extend `ClassO.Two` `Two` is an inner class inside `ClassO`. I am getting error

```
No enclosing instance of type ClassO is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation
```

What is the reason of difference in behaviour?

```
class ClassO
{   
    interface inner
    {
        void msg();
    }

    class Two implements inner
    {
        public void msg()
        {
            System.out.println("Class Two");
        }
    }

    static class Four 
    {
        public  void msg()
        {
            System.out.println("Class Four");
        }
    }

    public void m()
    {

    }
}

class T extends ClassO.Two  **// can extend ClassO.Four but not ClassO.Three**
{
    public void msg()
    {
        System.out.println("Class Two");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Non-static inner' is a tautology: [JLS #8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: And your title is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a static inner class is a "normal" class with the name nested inside its owner class, and additional access privileges to private static members of its owner class. As a result, static inner classes have no restrictions as to the location from which they could be instantiated.

In contrast, a non-static inner class has access to both static and non-static members of its owner class. To make this possible, Java compiler embeds a hidden pointer to the owner into the nested class, and passes an instance of the owner to that constructor.

This behavior relies on the availability of owner's `this` at the point of instantiation of the non-static inner class. If compiler were to allow you to inherit from a non-static member outside its owner, it wouldn't be able to instantiate your derived class, in effect forcing it to behave as if it were an inner class. That is why the compiler prohibits such inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain this line more - "This behavior relies on the availability of owner's this at the point of instantiation of the non-static inner class."

Comment: @bharatbhushan `class Two` has a hidden member `ClassO _owner_` (the name is probably different, but it is hidden anyway). Its constructor also has a hidden parameter `ClassO owner`. When you write `Two t = new Two();` inside a method of `ClassO`, Java compiler translates it to `Two t = new Two(this);`, so the whole business of manipulating the owner pointer is hidden from you. When the compiler says "No enclosing instance of type ClassO is available," it really says that there's no reference to pass to `Two`'s constructor.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms, and 'non-static inner' is a tautology: [JLS #8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: ...and yet everyone knows *exactly* what I am talking about, including site visitors with a knack for splitting hairs :-)